# Django manager annotate first element of m2m as fk

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Let's say I have these models.

```
class AdventureWaypoint(models.Model):
    adventure = models.ForeignKey("Adventure", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    waypoint = models.ForeignKey("Waypoint", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Waypoint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Adventure(models.Model):
    waypoints = models.ManyToManyField("Waypoint", through='AdventureWaypoint', related_name='waypoints')
    objects = AdventureManager()
```

How could I write a manager that annotates `first_waypoint` to every queryset?

I tried the following, but unfortunately `Subquery` doesn't work as expected. Couldn't use `F` as well.

```
class AdventureManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(AdventureManager).get_queryset()
        first_waypoint = AdventureWaypoint.objects.filter(adventure_id=OuterRef("id")).order_by('created_timestamp').first().waypoint
        return qs.annotate(first_waypoint=Subquery(first_waypoint, output_field=models.ForeignKey("Waypoint", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)))
```

Do I have to resort to raw SQL or how can this be done via Django ORM?

Note: I don't want to use @property as I want to use this annotated field in querysets e.g for filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this(according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)):

```
first_waypoint = AdventureWaypoint.objects.filter(adventure_id=OuterRef("id")).order_by('created_timestamp')
return qs.annotate(first_waypoint=Subquery(first_waypoint.values('waypoint')[:1]))
```

### Update

You can't add an actual instance like this. You can get only the name like this:

```
return qs.annotate(first_waypoint=Subquery(first_waypoint.values('waypoint__name')[:1]))
```

Or you can use `prefetch_related` to fetch the data to reduce database hit and access the value via for loop:

```
for adventure in Adventure.objects.prefetch_related('waypoints'):
   print(adventure.waypoints.first())
```

Comment: This does work, but is there a way to get the actual instance reference as well (as if it was fk)?
`adventure.first_waypoint` gives the id `1`. I would want to do `adventure.first_waypoint.name`.